# Add Class on last row in looping stripe and responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have column with blue strip on each row, all strip was generate from jquery base on how much rows.

The question is how to add class to the last strip if the row only have 1 or 2 boxs.
So if

- last row have 1 box then add `class='last'` to the strip
- last row have 2 box then add `class='half'` to the strip
- last row have 3 box dont add `class`

I create the strip with `class=dna`

this is my code :

```
function patternbig(){
var $dna = $("<div class='dna'></div>");
var boxHeight = $('.box').height()+20;
var topPos = 60;
var bx = $('.boxWrap').height()/$('.box').height();
var n= $('.box').length / 3;
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
        $dna.clone().css('top',topPos).appendTo('.entry');
        topPos += boxHeight;
    }
    $(".entry .dna").each(function(i) {
        $(this).addClass("pattern-" + (i+1));
    });
return false;
}
function patternsmall(){
var $dna = $("<div class='dna'></div>");
var boxHeight = $('.box').height()+20;
var topPos = 60;
var bx = $('.boxWrap').height()/$('.box').height();
var n= $('.box').length / 2;
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
        $dna.clone().css('top',topPos).appendTo('.entry');
        topPos += boxHeight;
    }
    $(".entry .dna").each(function(i) {
        $(this).addClass("pattern-" + (i+1));
});
return false;
}
debounce = function(func, wait, immediate) {
var timeout, args, context, timestamp, result;
return function() {
  context = this;
  args = arguments;
  timestamp = new Date();
  var later = function() {
    var last = (new Date()) - timestamp;
    if (last < wait) {
      timeout = setTimeout(later, wait - last);
    } else {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) result = func.apply(context, args);
    }
  };
  var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
  if (!timeout) {
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
  }
  if (callNow) result = func.apply(context, args);
  return result;
};
  };
//add dna pattern 
$(window).load(function () {
$(window).resize(debounce(function(){
        if ($(window).width() > 980) {
                $('.dna').hide();
                patternbig();
                return false;
        }
        if ($(window).width() < 979) {
                $('.dna').hide();
                patternsmall();
                return false;
        };
     
},1)); 
$(window).resize();

});
```

and this is [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/v3v7C/3/)

[image: this is what should look like]
this is what should look like if last row only have 2 boxes

---

I have fix this, if someone have same issue, you can check the code here - http://jsfiddle.net/v3v7C/10/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Modified the code bit:

```
 var n= $('.box').length / 3;
```

and css:

```
 @media(max-width:979px){.entrywrap{width:600px;} .box{ width:30%;}}
.dna:last-of-type{width: 66%;}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v3v7C/6/)**

Comment: Hi,thanks for this. in your jsfiddle link only have 3 column, how if I have 2 column when I resize browser? as you can see on my example that the column become 2 when we resize below 979px. and all the box will be dynamic so ont he bottom line may be contained 1,2 or 3 Boxes.

Comment: You might have to recalculate the width for last row on window resize and window load.

Comment: you mean recalculate this?.dna:last-of-type{width: 66%;}

Comment: Hi Milind, I have resolve this - http://jsfiddle.net/v3v7C/10/ thanks for your time.

Comment: Great that you are sharing the solution. hope helps someone in future.